# Progress Bar 100 percent complete when import the records from Excel File with File Upload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asynchronous

I am using asp.net with c#.

I imported the records from excel file with file upload control without iFrame or flash engine.

I want to show progress bar with 100 percentage complete.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry seeing a lot of code. Its simple to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Forms Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) for this.

HTML / ASPX Page

```
  <form id="myForm" action="fileupload.ashx" method="post"> 
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
        File: <input type="file" name="filetoupload" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
    </form>
   <progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
        // attach handler to form's submit event 
        $('#myFormId').submit(function () {
            // submit the form 
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                  uploadProgress:function(event,position,total){
                        $("progress").attr("max",total).attr("value",position);;
                       }
                 });
            // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pure HTML used in this example. If aspx webforms then, there will be only one form tag in a page.

Add a WebHandler (.ashx extension) to Website.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    HttpPostedFile MyFile=context.Request.Files["filetoupload"];
    if (MyFile.ContentLength > 0 && MyFile != null)
    {
        MyFile.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath("Path/On/Server"));
    }
    context.Response.Write("Saved Successfully");
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```